# BASH "for ... in ..." don't work with variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a simple script that does something for every file in user-defined directory. Here's a script that works for predefined directory:

```
for file in mydir/*; do

        printf "$file"

done
```

Here's similar script that prints name of each file in the directory defined by variable:

```
for file in "$nicedir*"; do

        printf "$file"

done
```

This second script don't work. Of course, I remembered about slash at the end of the path. (I passed ./ as the argument instead of just .)

Comment: What does echo $nicedir show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pathname expansion doesn't happen in quoted strings. Keep the wildcard outside of the quotes:

```
for file in "$nicedir"* ; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

The final slash is usually not required in paths, so you'll more often see

```
for file in "$nicedir/"*
# or equivalent
for file in "$nicedir"/*
```